# Whatsapp webhook won't connect with ngrok

Tags: laravel, webhooks, ngrok, whatsapi

I made a controller in laravel for WhatsApp webhook authentication, run it locally and use ngrok to connect it with WhatsApp webhook, it won't connect, it said "The Callback url or verify token could not be validated", but when I deploy it on heroku it working normally.
Is there any special config so I can connect it locally using ngrok ? or is there any alternative solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to follow the steps provided in ngrok documentation,
https://ngrok.com/docs/integrations/whatsapp/webhooks,

I am not sure which step you are missing or have a problem with, but as per the error "*The Callback url or verify token could not be validated*", your deployed code for webhook is not valid as per the provided guideline in [WhatsApp webhook docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/whatsapp/sample-app-endpoints).

> Make sure you have set the same verification code in the code and webhook verification when you configure!

Comment: and what should I do?

Comment: Ngrok is supposed to provide you with an HTTPS domain.

Comment: @GuillermoVerón I know but I just answered the exact requirement of the WhatsApp Business API.

Comment: I just tried this with ngrok just now and it's never accepted: always says the ngrok url is found to be malicious. The moment I switched to my hosted site, it works. But it is terribly inefficient to having to repeatedly move files to hosting just for testing during development. Would love to know a solution. Stumbled on https://ngrok.com/partners/whatsapp but it's not free.

Answer (score 1):

Went through the same issue and it seems that WhatsApp Cloud API considers NgRok malicious, and won't accept it as a callback webhook endpoint.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

According to the ngrok [docs](https://ngrok.com/docs/integrations/whatsapp/webhooks#:%7E:text=Note%3A%20This%20integration%20requires%20an%20ngrok%20Pro%20or%20Enterprise%20license%20because%20Facebook%20validates%20your%20ngrok%20domain%20and%20certificate.:%7E:text=Note%3A%20This%20integration%20requires%20an%20ngrok%20Pro%20or%20Enterprise%20license%20because%20Facebook%20validates%20your%20ngrok%20domain%20and%20certificate.), you need to have a pro or enterprise license for validation to work. A free alternate solution for anyone that may need it (at least at the time of writing) is Cloudflare tunnel. Just read the [docs](https://developers.cloudflare.com/cloudflare-one/connections/connect-apps/install-and-setup/tunnel-guide/) or you can watch this [video](https://youtu.be/hrwoKO7LMzk)(CLI version) or [video](https://youtu.be/Q5dG8g4-Sx0)(dashboard version) to help you set it up. You will need to have a domain though.

Answer (score 1):

I just managed to do it and I would like to explain how for others. First I logged into the ngrok website and claimed my free domain. Under the `Edges` tab you can than start a tunnel which will give give you a command, copy + paste that command into your `ngrok.exe` like usual.

After you've done that, tt will print your endpoint in the webapp after you click on `refresh`.

With that running setup your endpoint in your backend-project.

api.php:

```
Route::get('webhook', [WhatsappController::class, 'index']);
```

WhatsappController.php

```
public function index(Request $request): string
    {
        $hubChallenge = $request->input('hub_challenge');
        $verifyToken = $request->input('hub_verify_token');

        if ($request->input('hub_mode') === 'subscribe' && $verifyToken === env('VERIFY_TOKEN')) {
            return $hubChallenge;
        } else {
            return response('Bad Request', 400);
        }
    }
```

in my `.env` file I created a variable called `VERIFY_TOKEN` and gave it a value. Enter that same value into the `verify token` field in the `meta.developer` portal when creating an endpoint.

For the `Callback Url` use the url that ngrok gave you together with (in my case) `/api/webhook`.

After all these steps it should work locally.

Answer (score 1):

After applying @PioPio answer, I hit another hurdle when getting event notifications from whatsapp webhook. This is what worked for me.

1. Change the webhook url to accept both GET and POST requests i.e.

```
Route::match(['GET', 'POST'], 'webhook', [WhatsappController::class, 'index']);
```

After doing this I started receiving error `419 unknown status` from my app. Realized that this was due to **CSRF Verification**. To address this I followed the steps below to exclude my webhook route from CSRF verification:

1. Open the `VerifyCSRFToken.php` file, typically located in the `app/Http/Middleware` directory.
2. Inside the VerifyCSRFToken middleware, find the `except` property. This property contains an array of routes that are exempt from CSRF verification.
3. Add your webhook route to the except array. This informs Laravel to skip CSRF verification for this specific route.

```
protected $except = [
    'your/webhook/route',
];
```

Replace `your/webhook/route` with the actual route you are using for your webhook.

4. Save the changes and try receiving the webhook POST request again.

This adjustment allowed my app to accept webhook requests without CSRF verification issues.

Note: I was using a free ngrok domain for this.