# Error when setting up webhook with Ngrok/WhatsApp

Tags: node.js, whatsapp, ngrok

I am trying to setup a WhatsApp bot using voiceflow, based on the tutorial found [here](https://developer.voiceflow.com/docs/whatsapp-custom). I've set this up before and everything has worked fine, but now I can't seem to configure the webhook.

The steps I'm performing are as follows:

1. Clone the repo [here](https://github.com/voiceflow/example-integration-whatsapp)
2. Checked ngrok is installed (version 3.0.7), and its location (/usr/local/bin/ngrok)
3. Created a .env file at the root with the VERIFY_TOKEN, PORT, and WHATSAPP_TOKEN
4. Started the app from root with `npm start`
5. Started ngrok with `ngrok http 8000` (the same port as specified in my .env)
6. Checked the resulting address works in the browser

According to the documentation, I then configure the webhook by adding "/webhook" to the end of the URL, and adding the same VERIFY_TOKEN as specified in my .env file. This, however, gives me the following error:

**The callback URL or verify token couldn't be validated.
Please verify the provided information or try again later.**

I've had a look around at similar questions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73303493/whatsapp-webhook-wont-connect-with-ngrok), but could not find what was wrong. I have also spoken to others who encountered similar issues over the last few weeks. This process was working up until recently (Nov 2022).

Answer (score 0):

The error msg: `The callback URL or verify token couldn't be validated. Please verify the provided information or try again later.` usually means you are not returning a 200 response to the webhook origin. I would make sure your code is returning a 200 to whatsapp.

As an alternative, try to set the webhook on glitch as explained here:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/whatsapp/sample-app-endpoints#cloud-api-sample-app-endpoint

so that you can check if your meta account is valid.

Answer (score 0):

From what I have found it seems that feature is now behind a paywall. It worked fine a few months ago on the free tier of ngrok. So you will need to upgrade your ngrok subscription for WhatsApp to start validating. You can read about it [here](https://ngrok.com/docs/integrations/whatsapp/webhooks#:%7E:text=Note%3A%20This%20integration%20requires%20an%20ngrok%20Pro%20or%20Enterprise%20license%20because%20Facebook%20validates%20your%20ngrok%20domain%20and%20certificate.). Try using [Cloudflare tunnel](https://developers.cloudflare.com/cloudflare-one/connections/connect-apps/install-and-setup/tunnel-guide/remote/).